# Python Perforce module Error: No module named 'P4'

Tags: python, perforce, blender

I got the P4 python module for win10 via the installer on their page: https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-core-api-python

Its for python 3.9, though I have tested it with both Python 3.10 and 3.9 and it always throws the error: No module named 'P4' when I try to use it inside visual code.

Interpreter is set up correctly (tried 310 and 39).

Im a bit lost here and would love some help.
The installer package installed the following files into site-packages:
P4.py
P4API.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
and a folder with 4 metadata files in it

P4.py on itself looks good, no errors.

Edit: Im trying to use it with Blender. Currently shipped python version within that is 3.10.2. Also tried a older blender version which uses 3.9.7.
Both wont work.

Comment: Why not just do `pip install p4python`?

Comment: It was throwing the error: need parameter: --ssl.

If i try pip install p4python now it will just say that all requirements are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio code is known for it's bugs with python. You could try using "PyCharm". Make sure to install the modules from Pycharm's settings instead of terminal.

(I'm not sure if this is the reason, but it's worth the try. Had the same issue and the mentioned way solved it.)